# Content sliders CSS z-index property not working properly in the Edge browser

Tags: html, css

for some reason the z-index property is not working properly in the Edge browser which should display the arrow I'm hovering over at full opacity until removed. For example, when I click an arrow a second time to view the next slide the current arrows full opacity is not on until I move the mouse again. I was wondering if it's possible to keep the current arrow in full opacity until the mouse pointer is not hovering over the arrow any longer?

I was wondering if there is a way to fix this for the Edge browser since in all the other browsers this is working perfectly.

Here is the link to the Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ef2bvkqb/

HTML

```
<form class="sliders">
    <input type="radio" name="slider-choice" id="first-slider" checked />
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider">
            <p>Some Random Text...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="second-slider" class="prev"></label>
            <label for="second-slider" class="next"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="radio" name="slider-choice" id="second-slider" />
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider">
            <p>Even Some More Random Text...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="first-slider" class="prev"></label>
            <label for="first-slider" class="next"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.sliders {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

.sliders input{ 
    display: none; 
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 600px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

.nav label {
  margin-top: 65px;
    width: 85px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: black;
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .6);
    Z-index: 99999;
}

.sliders:hover .nav label{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sliders:hover .prev:hover, .sliders:hover .next:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav .next{ 
    right: 0;
}

.prev:before{
    content: '\2770';
}

.next:before{
    content: '\2771';
}

input:checked + .slider-container .slider{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slider-container .nav label{ 
    display: block; 
}

p{
    padding: 100px 20px;
    width: 560px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #dae1ef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the arrows are inside each slide, I mean each slide has it's own arrows.

You need to put the arrows outside the slides, and only one couple of the arrows and you gonna need to use JavaScript instead of using only CSS3 to animate.

Comment: Is there a CSS solution?

Comment: As far as i know, there isn't a solution for your situation here, because the thing is on Microsoft Edge, the arrow of the next slide needs the mouse to move or to re-hover again in order update the element state(focused, hovered,...)